# Are \count1, ..., \count9 useful?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, dvi

To quote *TeX by Topic*, "whenever a `\shipout` occurs, TeX also writes the values of counters 0–9 to the dvi file and the terminal."

Do any dvi viewers or converters (e.g., dvips) make use of `\count1`, `\count2`, …, `\count9`?

Do any TeX formats or LaTeX packages set them?

Does pdfTeX (when outputting pdfs) use them?

Comment: Just citing the TeXbook here: «Registers numbered 0 to 9 are always free for temporary “scratch” use, but their values are always assumed to be clobbered whenever any other macro might get into control. (This applies to registers like `\dimen0`, `\toks0`, `\skip1`, `\box3`, etc.; but TEX has already reserved `\count0` through `\count9` for page number identiﬁcation.)»

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pdftex-based version of ConTeXt uses `\count1` to indicate the user-visible page number, and `\count0` for the sequential page number in the pdf. So in a book with 4 pages of preliminary matter (colophon, toc) there will be `[5.1]`
printed to the terminal for the first page in the main document body.

Comment: Very clever idea: I shall keep that one in mind :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's the `count1to` package, which stores sectioning numbers in them, but that's the only thing that comes to my mind.